# Auto-flowing Blocks in Beamer/BeamerPoster environment?

Tags: beamer, columns, beamerposter

What I have:
Multi-column beamerposter with blocks in each column

```
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}
        \begin{block}{A Block}
            ...
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{A Block}
            ...
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}
        \begin{block}{A Block}
            ...
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}{A Block}
            ...
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

What I would *like* to do:

```
\begin{columns}{2}
    \begin{block}{A Block}
        ...
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{A Block}
        ...
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{A Block}
        ...
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{A Block}
        ...
    \end{block}
\end{columns}
```

Basically what I'm trying to head towards is a `beamerposter` template that will let me easily switch between portrait and landscape views for instance by setting the columns to 2 (as above) in the portrait version and to 3 in the landscape, with blocks being arranged in order top to bottom as they fit.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want balanced columns? Well the beamer author explains at several locations in the guide, that he does think a good presentation should be carefully and manually arranged. So you might try another package like `multicol` for balancing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `beamer` columns system simply doesn't work like this: behind the scenes everything is done in a fixed way, with the idea being that for a presentation (or indeed a poster) positioning is important and automatic flowing is now what is wanted. As mentioned in a comment, if you want flowing text then a more 'standard' multi-column approach such as that offered by `multicol` is probably the best plan.